# Unexpected result from building react-app

Tags: reactjs, build, create-react-app, npm-start, npm-run

I have issue when building newest versions of React. 
When I run npm run build it builds in chunks.

Result of build:

```
File sizes after gzip:

  34.45 KB  build/static/js/1.2dd891c4.chunk.js
  763 B     build/static/js/runtime~main.229c360f.js
  711 B     build/static/js/main.f219991b.chunk.js
  509 B     build/static/css/main.ef7da6c0.chunk.css
```

I am not using webpack, and I haven't modified anything. I installed it using create-react-app.
This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

How to force react build to build in following format:

```
  711 B     build/static/js/main.f219991b.js
  509 B     build/static/css/main.ef7da6c0.css
```

Link to repository which contains build files:
https://github.com/Tararan/joes-coffee-store

Comment: I'm not sure that you are able to change the way that create-react-app building your applicaiton unless you eject your app from create-react-app and change it by yourself in webpack config. Create-react-app is still using webpack in background.

Comment: @prius by default create-react-app will have webpack configured into itself. if you run npm run eject , you can see the webpack configuration. can you share the link to your codebase?

Comment: I linked my repository which contains build folder.

My issue is that in version 16.4.2  (when I first experimented with React) I used sass so I changed the way react builds and runs my application so that it builds sass as well. 
In that case build didn't contain chunks and I didn't eject react